# Setting environment variables in TeamCity and accessing them via php

Tags: php, teamcity

I've set an environment variable in my build configuration in TeamCity.

[image]

Specs are:

```
text display='normal' 
validationMode='not_empty'
```

But the output of `var_dump(_ENV)` is an empty array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `var_dump($_SERVER); or var_dump($_ENV);`

Comment: Just did:
output of var_dump($_ENV) is still an empty array
only thing that could be of interest of the output of $_SERVER ist probably this:
 ["SOMETHING_ENV"]=> string(10) "production"

Comment: are you running `var_dump(_ENV)`as part of the build script? the `env.` vars you assign a TC build only exist for the duration of the build configuration run; if you're expecting them to persist in a running web app, that won't be the case.